# Improve OCR results with Google-Vision

Tags: node.js, computer-vision, google-vision

I'm trying to run OCR on a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNDQR.jpg)(2048x1152) from Twitch (for Dota/LOL).

before sending that screenshot to Google-Vision I'm applying a black and white filter:

```
export function imageToBW(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loadImage(filename).then((image) => {
      const canvas = createCanvas(image.width,image.height)
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


      ctx.fillStyle = 'white'

      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      // set the gCO
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'luminosity';

      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

      resolve(canvas.toBuffer())
    }).catch(err => reject(err))
  })
}
```

this is the "[parsed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofrzx.jpg)"
the problem is that google is detecting a lot of text but not the main thing I want: The scores on top...

Is there another filter or something that would get me better results?
I tried multiple filters and screenshot sizes but I never get the most important piece of text :D

Thank you

Comment: try simple resize first. shrink the image down a bit  10% or 20% . then try it again. Becasue all smaller size word are picked up. only this big score not piced up.    The other way is the crop the image only to top middle part.  DOTA2 always have score there. so only sendin the correct section

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai I did try to downsize the image using multiple ratios and nothing worked

Comment: even crop to that region and it is still not working? If crop to that area and it is not working, then it might be font issue. try too search for font parameter in google ocr

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai unfortunately crop doesn't work. Google vision has no parameters for font

Comment: If crop doesnt work, the only chance left is to find exact font for OCR to work.  Font selection/training is a common process  see  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Fonts

Comment: I checked google vision currently not support tweak in fonts.  You have to use google open source versions of Tesseract OCR to complete this. And link back to google vision routing. In theory, it is possible, in practice, a lot of trouble.

Comment: thank you @DrYuanShenghai. I'll look into that or just go all-in with openCV and train my own model